# yii 1.1 dropDownList with parent Category Name

Tags: php, yii

We have the Categories table with columns:
id
parent_id
title

Also we have the **relation**:

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
                    'Parent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Categories', 'parent_id'),
        );
    }
```

We use the **function**:

```
public function getFullCategory() 
{
          $showparentname = 'Parent.title';
              return $this->$showparentname.' - '.$this->title;
}
```

The **form dropDownList** use:

```
$categories = Categories::model()->findAll();
$categories_list = CHtml::listData($categories, 'id', 'FullCategory');
```

But it doesn't work

> Property "Categories.Parent.title" is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use 'Parent.title', it's triing to get $this->Parent.title property. Use this:

```
function getTitleWithParent(){
    return ( $this->Parent !== null ? $this->Parent->title.' - ' : '' ).$this->title;
}
```